# No available buckets in NiFi in dialogue "Start version control"

Tags: apache-nifi

Setup:

- secured NiFi and secured NiFi-Registry on same host
- Users and groups are configured with LDAP/AD. Meaning, I have no local users but NiFi and NiFi-Registry retrieve users and groups from AD.
- bucket created in NiFi-Registry
- added the read, write and delete privileges for user groups.
- NiFi is connected to NiFi-Registry: If I mistype the hostname or port, I get different errors.
- TRACE activated in nifi and nifi-registry logs

**Problem**:
NiFi is not showing the buckets from NiFi-Registry. I can't select anything. It just displays **"No available buckets"**.

From the logs I could see what APIs are called.

When I manually call the API against NiFi-Registry

```
https://<hostname nifi-registry>:18443/nifi-registry-api/buckets
```

I get the result

> [{"allowBundleRedeploy":false,"allowPublicRead":false,"createdTimestamp":1668709528688,"identifier":"25388221-2d2e-4b64-a584-a6e8c73416b2","link":{"href":"buckets/25388221-2d2e-4b64-a584-a6e8c73416b2","params":{"rel":"self"}},"name":"my-bucket-name","permissions":{"canDelete":true,"canRead":true,"canWrite":true},"revision":{"version":0}}]

which lists my bucket and shows the correct permissions.

The nifi logs show a different API call to nifi itsself:

```
https://<nifi hostname>:8443/nifi-api/flow/registries/100811d4-1000-1410-a7bd-b2b3126d3565/buckets
```

with the result

> {"buckets":[]}

Calling

```
https://<nifi hostname>/nifi-api/flow/registries
```

returns correctly the registry-id `100811d4-1000-1410-a7bd-b2b3126d3565`

> {"registries":[{"revision":{"clientId":"9b249b2e-0184-1000-ff0f-5419dc497385","version":4},
> "id":"100811d4-1000-1410-a7bd-b2b3126d3565",
> "uri":"https://nifi-hostname:8443/nifi-api/controller/registry-clients/100811d4-1000-1410-a7bd-b2b3126d3565",
> "permissions":{"canRead":true,"canWrite":true},"registry":{"id":"100811d4-1000-1410-a7bd-b2b3126d3565","name":"my-registry-name","description":"",
> "uri":"https://nifi-registry-ostname:18443",
> "type":"org.apache.nifi.registry.flow.NifiRegistryFlowRegistryClient","bundle":{"group":"org.apache.nifi","artifact":"nifi-flow-registry-client-nar","version":"1.18.0"}
> ....

Comment: hit with this issue too. any fix @svebert?

Comment: I tried 1000 different things. So I cannot fully recover what did fix it. I think the main ingredient was including the nifi hosts in authorizers.xml. In the tag <accessPolicyProvider> I included <property name="NiFi Identity 1">CN=your-nifi-hostname.org, OU=YourOU, O=YOURORG, ST=YourCity, C=YourCountryCode</property>. I also included the same <property> in <userGroupProvider>-Tag